# MySQL LIKE wildcard for table

Tags: mysql, wildcard, sql-like

I have a PHP document which will execute some MySQL and echoes it back.

Code:
`$query1 = "SELECT * FROM feed, recipients WHERE feed.title LIKE \"%recipients.suburb%"\ ORDER BY pubDate DESC";`

recipients.suburb (table.column) is in my MySQL DB. How can I perform wildcards on this?

This works, but I can't do it for tables?

`$query1 = "SELECT * FROM feed, recipients WHERE feed.title LIKE '%test%' ORDER BY pubDate DESC";`

I'd like to check the column `feed.title` and see if any of this text is in `recipients.suburb`. It is for a script that will eventually email users, based on text from MySQL co-relating to the location of the user.

Comment: What do you mean by *This works, but I cant do it to tables?*

Comment: It works for values, but not for variables. There isnt a column "test", just using it as a value. 

There is a column for "suburb". I want to use this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM feed, recipients 
WHERE feed.title LIKE concat('%', recipients.suburb, '%')
ORDER BY pubDate DESC
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Works perfectly.

Will try js1568's suggestion too.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off with a better E-R design where you have a `suburb` table with an id. Then you can have foreign key `suburb_id` in both the `feed` table and the `recipients` table. This would create a many-to-many relationship between `feed` and `recipient` that you are looking for here.

The solution would then be to use joins to match recipients to feeds where the suburb is the same.

Here is what I would propose:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feed` (
  `feed_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `suburb` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NULL,
  `pubDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`feed_id`)
  UNIQUE KEY `feed_id` (`feed_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recipients` (
  `recipient_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `suburb` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`recipient_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `recipient_id` (`recipient_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `suburb` (
  `suburb_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`suburb_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `suburb_id` (`suburb_id`)
);
```

And use this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT feed.title, recipients.name, suburb.name
FROM feed, recipients, suburb
WHERE feed.suburb = suburb.suburb_id
AND suburb.suburb_id = recipients.suburb
AND feed.title LIKE CONCAT(  '%', suburb.name,  '%' ) 
ORDER BY pubDate DESC
```

Comment: Ok, I might experiment around with this. Never created a foreign key.